# Why does this give me the error string indices must be integers?

Tags: python

```
lloyd = {
"name": "Lloyd",
"homework": [90, 97, 75, 92],
"quizzes": [88, 40, 94],
"tests": [75, 90]
}
alice = {
    "name": "Alice",
    "homework": [100, 92, 98, 100],
    "quizzes": [82, 83, 91],
    "tests": [89, 97]
}
tyler = {
    "name": "Tyler",
    "homework": [0, 87, 75, 22],
    "quizzes": [0, 75, 78],
    "tests": [100, 100]
}
def average(stuff):
    return sum(stuff)/len(stuff)

def getLetterGrade(score):
    score = round(score)
    if  score >= 90: return "A"
    elif  90 > score >= 80: return "B"
    elif  80 > score >= 70: return "C"
    elif  70 > score >= 60: return "D"
    elif  60 > score: return "F"

def getAverage(kid):
    bar = average
    return bar(kid["homework"])*.1 + bar(kid["quizzes"])*.3 + bar(kid["tests"])*.6

students = ["lloyd","alice","tyler"]

#takes students list
def getClassAverage(list, total = 0):
    for x in list:
        total += getAverage(x)
    return total / len(list)

#takes students list
def classAvgFull(list):
    print getClassAverage(list)
    print getLetterGrade(getClassAverage(list))

classAvgFull(students)
```

I honestly just can't figure out where I've gone wrong here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.  I'm sure it is just something simple.  Very very beginning of my learning, using codeacademy.com  Thank you in advance!

Comment: So ... which line troubles you?

Comment: do you mean to do `bar * (kid["homework"])*.1` in place of `bar(kid["homework"])*.1` ?

Answer (score 10):

Change

```
students = ["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]
```

to

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
```

---

It is important to know how to debug this kind of problem yourself.

The error message tells you the problem occurs on this line:

```
return bar(kid["homework"])*.1 + bar(kid["quizzes"])*.3 + bar(kid["tests"])*.6
```

and the error has something to do with indexing:

```
string indices must be integers, not str
```

A natural question is, *what is the value of `kid`*? So try putting in a print statement before the error occurs:

```
bar = average
print(repr(kid))
return bar(kid["homework"])*.1 + bar(kid["quizzes"])*.3 + bar(kid["tests"])*.6
```

You'll find that it prints

```
'lloyd'
```

Now the natural question becomes, *how come `kid` is a string,* `'lloyd'`? and *What did we really want?* (answer: the dict, `lloyd`). If you search for where `getAverage(kid)` gets called, you find yourself looking at the `getClassAverage` function:

```
def getClassAverage(list, total = 0):
    for x in list:
        total += getAverage(x)
```

And now the natural question becomes, *How come `x` is the string `'lloyd'`?* and *What are the values in `list`?*  Again you can use print statements to find the answer. And of course, *Where are we calling getClassAverage(list, ...)?*

If you keep tracking back in this way, you finally arrive at

```
students = ["lloyd", "alice", "tyler"]
```

and you'll realize it should be

```
students = [lloyd, alice, tyler]
```

---

Never name a variable `list`. It shadows the builtin of the same name. It is best to use a descriptive name such as `students` because then your variable names help document the meaning of your code.  If the variable is meant to represent a generic sequence, I recommend a variable name like `seq` or `iterable`.

Comment: To explain: In your current code, instead of sending the object `lloyd`, you are sending the string "lloyd". Thus when you then do `kid["homework"]` that's an error because you can index into a string like that.

Comment: OH.  that is simple.  Thank you guys very much!

Answer (score 0):

def get_class_average(students):

```
results = []

for student in students:

    x= get_average(student)
    results.append(x)
return average(results)
```

This function sure did work for me!